# AWS : verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

i try to clone project by using HTTPS(GRC)
but i have error
i try to find problem with (_ssl.c:1000)

`raise SSLError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e) botocore.exceptions.SSLError: SSL validation failed for https://sts.amazonaws.com/  [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)`